# HTML empty button has spacing on top & bottom with !DOCTYPE, but no space without !DOCTYPE

Tags: html, doctype

I've just runned into a special case where an empty button with no with/height/border, renders some spacing on top & bottom of it, if !DOCTYPE is specified.

This example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>asda</div>
<button style="padding: 0;margin: 0;height: 0;width: 0;border: 0;"></button>
<div>asda</div>

</body>
</html>
```

will visually produce this output:

[image]

If I remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` then no spacing will be there. Of course, doctype needs to be kept.

**The question is**: how can I remove the spacing while having *doctype*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A button element is inline. Change it to `display:block;` and your properties will do what you want, though I think `padding:0;` is all you need.

Comment: padding & border, but I've added here all properties just to show up that nothing else is responsible for the spacing. 
So indeed it does do the trick with display block, but not with inline-block. Strange behaviour though....